# Node.JS Promises and Logging in

Tags: node.js, promise

I'm learning about Node.js and also Express.js, and attempting to create a forum like website in the process of such,

I currently want the user to be able to register an account, and then log into it which is handled via MongoDB using Mongoose

```
async function FindUser(username)
{
    return new Promise((res, rej) =>{
        UserModel.findOne({username: username}, (err, user)=>{
            if (err)
                rej(error);
            if (!user)
                rej("User not found..");
            res(user);
        })
    })
}

module.exports.loginUser = async function(username, password)
{
    return new Promise((res, rej) =>{
        let User = await FindUser(username);
        // Other logic below..


        // We've logged in!
        res()
    });
}
```

After the resolve, we simply go back to a router where it handles the promise.

I'm not sure if this is how I should be using promises, and if anyone can provide insight on how to handle these async tasks, it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked mongoose documentation. Seems like it supports promises already. See [this](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html).

So, there is no need to call `new Promise` directly:

```
async function FindUser(username) {
    return await UserModel.findOne({username: username}).exec();
}

module.exports.loginUser = async function(username, password) {
    user = await FindUser(username);
    /* Doing user things here */
    return user;
}
```

Note: you hardly ever need to create promise *yourself*, most of the time this is considered antipattern.